# FuseIt WSDL is not able to parse

Tags: wsdl2apex

i'm trying to parse wsdl URL: https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl
but got following error.[image]

I tried parsing wsdl in different org but got the same error. Please let me know if there is any work around solution for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the WSDL isn't valid.

[image: Invalid WSDL]

Notice how there are two complex types called "EziResponseOfString" and an element as well. All in the same namespace.

The code can't add an Apex Class to represent the complex type because it has already generated one with the same name.

One point of difference is in the casing. The first has a lower case s (EziResponseOf**s**tring) and the second uppercase (EziResponseOf**S**tring). This is a problem for Apex as it is case insensitive. It *might* be possible to have the code append a suffix to the second complexType. However, I'd recommend updating the service if you can to remove the confusion.

Comment: Thank You Daniel, i deleted EziResponseOfString it worked thanks a lot for the explanation